# style the two parts of the value String different

Tags: css, primefaces

I have the following tag of primefaces

```
<p:outputLabel readonly="true" value="${displayHelper.getValue('CONTEXT_1')} ${displayHelper.getDescription('CONTEXT_1')}"   />
```

to display some information.

the result of `${displayHelper.getValue('CONTEXT_1')} ${displayHelper.getDescription('CONTEXT_1')}"` is 100%.
Now I want to display the result of vlaue as **100** (also bold) with "%" (small) without bold. How can I manage that in this case?

Also result should look like **100**  %

Comment: you can't style parts of text. you can only apply styles to DOM elements as a whole, which means the bits you want to style differently will have to be wrapped in a DOM element, e.g. a `<span>`

Comment: You indeed need to do this like you would in plain html. Since that is what it on the client-side all is... html, css, js... Nothing more